# Is there any environments like Visual Studio for embedded systems?

Tags: embedded-systems

I thought it would be very useful if there is an embedded application development tool like Visual Studio for web development. I mean when we develop web applications we have a toolbox and we drag and drop components and generally use events. In embedded systems events are interrupts. So why don't we have a toolbox which has electronic circuit components and we drag and drop them, also by clicking on them writing the behind code. Is there any extension like that for visual studio? or Is there any other environment like that?

Comment: _"Is there any other environment..."_ -- **[resource requests are not quite welcome at Programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5454/31260 "as discussed eg here")**. As far as I understand, one would rather present an **underlying problem** instead - a problem that was intended to be solved with particular resource requested

Answer (score 3):

For Atmel AVR embedded microcontroller there is the [Atmel Studio](http://www.atmel.com/tools/atmelstudio.aspx) which makes writing c/c++/assembly and their debugging quite comfortable.